# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Membership.CreateUser Email Address Verification Issue

Tags: asp.net, validation, asp.net-membership

I'm currently using ASP.NET 2.0 Forms Authentication on our company customer facing web site.

When a customer activates their account for the first time through the site, their email is populated from the database along with their full name.
After they enter their `username`, `security question`, `security answer`, and `password`, all these parameters are passed into `Membership.CreateUser`.
For customers that have a **one letter domain email** such as *kim@q.com* or *john@k.com*, the `Membership.CreateUser` **email validation returns invalid email address and doesn't create the users membership until they enter a valid email address**.

Is there a fix our work around for the one letter email validation issue that anyone is aware of?  Any bit of advice would be helpful.

Comment: Apparently, the only way to bypass the validation is to use a specific MembershipProvider. See last answer from this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038695/asp-net-mvc-custom-membership-provider-createuser

Comment: Dude, try this link... http://forums.asp.net/p/1788877/4945108.aspx/1?Re+create+user+wizard+email+validation there is a little workaround.